# use multiple Form Action Based On Radio Button Selection

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

```
<p><h3 style="font-size:18px;">Call Status:</h3>

<body>
<div>
<form action="immediate.php">
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" <?php if (isset($colorRadio) && $colorRadio=="immediate" ) echo "checked";?>value="IMMEDIATE"> Call Immediate</label>
</form>

<form action="scheduled.php">   
   <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" <?php if (isset($colorRadio) && $colorRadio=="scheduled") echo "checked";?> value="SCHEDULED"> Call Scheduled</label>

      </form></div>
<div class="IMMEDIATE box">You have selected <strong>red radio button</strong> so i am here</div>

<div class="SCHEDULED box"><p>
    <td>
<input type="Text" id="demo1" name="demo1" maxlength="25" size="25"><a href="javascript:NewCal('demo1','DDMMYYYY',true,24)">
<img src="img/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0"></a>
<span class="descriptions">Pick a Date</span>
    </p></div>
```

Hi Sir this is my code...I just want to add multiple form action on selection of radio button... Call Immediate radio button is selected then send my form at `immediate.php` page and if Call Scheduled is selected then then page send on `scheduled.php` page

Answer (score 0):

Its easier with jQuery. Basic version is:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="basic" value="a.html" onclick="setLocation(this)" checked="checked" />

function setLocation(element) {
        document.forms[0].action = element.value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an example for you

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function select()
    {
     var1=document.getElementById("radio1");
     var2=document.getElementById("radio2");
     if(var1.checked==true)
     {
        document.myform.action="immediate.php";
     }
     else
     {
        document.myform.action="Scheduled.php";
     }
   }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="immediate.php" method="post" name="myform" onsubmit="select()">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="colorRadio" value="IMMEDIATE"> 
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="colorRadio" value="Call SCHEDULED">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

It check for selected radio button when submit is clicked and assign action based on selection.
Hope it helps